# Qt app permissions not granted on recent (>6) Android devices

Tags: android, c++, qt

Using Qt 5.14.2, with NDK r21b, I create this simple program:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDir>
#include <QStandardPaths>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QDialog dlg;

    dlg.setLayout( new QVBoxLayout() );

    QString path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation);

    if ( !QDir(path).exists() )
    {
        if ( QDir().mkdir(path) )
            dlg.layout()->addWidget( new QLabel( "Could create folder " + path, &dlg ) );
        else
            dlg.layout()->addWidget( new QLabel( "Could NOT create folder " + path, &dlg ) );
    }
    else
    {
        dlg.layout()->addWidget( new QLabel( "Folder exists " + path, &dlg ) );
    }

    path += "/from_qt.txt";

    QFile file(path);
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream << "something" << endl;
        dlg.layout()->addWidget( new QLabel( "Could create file " + path, &dlg ) );
    }
    else
    {
        dlg.layout()->addWidget( new QLabel( "Could NOT create file " + path, &dlg ) );
    }

    dlg.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

- Using Android 5, when installing the apk, the system reports the app needs to access storage and later the app will work (it reports `Could NOT create...`).
- Using Android 6, when installing the apk, the system does not report the app needs any special access and later the app will work.

Comment: Please tell full path you use. And the errors/exceptions/problems you get.

Comment: What do you call recent if you only mention Android version 5 and 6?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes:

> Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant and revoke app
> permissions at run time, instead of doing so when they install the
> app. As a result, you'll have to test your app under a wider range of
> conditions. Prior to Android 6.0, you could reasonably assume that if
> your app is running at all, it has all the permissions it declares in
> the app manifest. Beginning with Android 6.0 the user can turn
> permissions on or off for any app, even an app that targets API level
> 22 or lower. You should test to ensure your app functions correctly
> whether or not it has any permissions.

So you need to add `QT += androidextras` in .pro file, include `<QtAndroid>` and add in the code:

```
auto  result = QtAndroid::checkPermission(QString("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"));
        if(result == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied){
            QtAndroid::PermissionResultMap resultHash = QtAndroid::requestPermissionsSync(QStringList({"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"}));
            if(resultHash["android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"] == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied)
                return 1;
        }
```

Comment: You have been sleeping all that time?

Comment: @blackapps: What does that mean?

Comment: That you have not updated and maintained your code since October 5, 2015 the release date of Android M. And that is not what i would call a recent version.

Comment: I updated my code....what has not been updated is the devices it's running on. If you stick with Android 5 there is absolutely no problem.

Comment: @blackapps: And believe it or not...I even found an Android 4.4 device here! ;-)